# Can a SignalR Application run on IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Plain and simple: Is it even possible for a SignalR Application to run off IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2, or is this not a compatible setup? There are tons of threads all over Stack Overflow that pose the same issue, that the dynamically generated script located at signalr/hubs is 404ing, but the threads with solutions are not using my iis/server setup.

I tried following the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr but it seems that it only works in Visual Studio's IIS Express. As soon as I move the application to our server, I get the error everyone else on SO is getting.

Here's the supported platforms for Signalr on the official documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

It stops short of Windows Server 2012 R2, but the documentation is dated. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I have a SignalR app in production for a long time now on the platforms mentioned without issue.

Comment: Post relevant code, explain environment better etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2016 both support SignalR. Just ensure WebSocket support is enabled and you're all set.

IIS Express is a cut-down version of IIS (which frustratingly does not work with IIS Manager), but internally it uses the same execution engine (including `HTTP.sys` integration) so it uses the same `web.config` files as the full-fat IIS too, so it supports SignalR too.

("IIS Express" is a thing because previously VS shipped with a simple web-server called Cassini, which used ASP.NET `System.Web.dll` for everything, which worked for simple applications but for more complex applications there was sufficient differing behaviour that it made development difficult)

Comment: @klabranche Without WebSockets enabled SignalR falls back to legacy techniques like long-polling - so for the best performance and user-experience you should enable and use WebSockets.

Comment: Understood. :-) I just wanted to be clear that with or without WebSockets, SignalR works on the stated platform. The answer could be taken to be a reason as to why it wasn't working to anyone reading the question/answer.

Comment: @klabranche since you've deployed on the same platform, any advice here? I posted a question with code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237137/signalr-example-app-from-official-documentation-does-not-work-on-iis

Comment: @johnny-pints Your missing ~/ on all your pathing... You moved from localhost to a server where the relativity matters.....  instead of src="signalr/hubs" try src="~/signalr/hubs"